# PHP regex - unable to match. Variable has '\r\n'

Tags: php, regex, string

Having some trouble with what seems a simple match operation. I'm pretty sure some knowledgeable person knows what i'm missing here...

```
$errors = array(
    "Error: Unrecognized command found at '^' position",
);

if (in_array($result, $errors)) {
    //do something
}
```

When I echo out $result, it returns

```
"Error: Unrecognized command found at '^' position"
```

But it is not found in the array. When i echo out as json:

```
"^\r\nError: Unrecognized command found at '^' position"
```

I tried using preg_replace to remove ^\r\n, but still no match. Any ideas?

Comment: Show the `preg_replace` code you are using.

Comment: Use [`trim()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.trim.php)?

Comment: Never `echo` variables to check what they contain. Always `var_dump()` them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is because you were looking for the `\r` and `\n` special characters instead of litterals. You can use the `\` escape character to fix this:

`^\\r\\n`

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NcTz1e/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ltrim`](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.trim.php) function and explicitly specify the characters you want to remove, including `^`:

```
$str = ltrim("^\r\nError: Unrecognized command found at '^' position", "^\r\n");
var_dump($str);
// string(49) "Error: Unrecognized command found at '^' position"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str_replace`

Please find the below snippet which works absolutely fine:

```
$errors = array(
"Error: Unrecognized command found at '^' position",
);
$result = "\r\nError: Unrecognized command found at '^' position";
$result = str_replace("\r\n", '', $result);
if (in_array($result, $errors)) {
  echo 'Hello World!';
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
```